# Clear method removes all links in all Hashmap's objects

Tags: java

I was shocked when I saw that when I cleaned the inner map, after earlier adding it to the outer map. Is there any way to reset the internal map but to not remove objects from the map of the outer?

main class:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person per1 = new Person("1", "aaa",56, true);
        Person per2 = new Person("20", "bbb",34, false);

        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Person>> outer = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Person>>();

        Map<Integer, Person> inner = new HashMap<Integer, Person>();

        inner.put(100, per1);
        inner.put(200, per2);

        outer.put(1000, inner);
        // inner: size = 2 , outer: size = 1 (key = 1000, value size = 2)
        inner.clear();
        // inner: size = 0 , outer: size = 1 (key = 1000, value size = 0) 
        // why outer value size = 0 ?
}
```

Person:

```
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean isSome;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean isSome() {
        return isSome;
    }

    public void setSome(boolean isPaid) {
        this.isSome = isPaid;
    }
    public Person(){}

    public Person(String id, String name, int age, boolean isSome){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.isSome = isSome;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outer.put(1000, inner);` puts the reference contained in the `inner` variable as a value in the outer Map. It doesn't create a copy of the instance referred by `inner`, so if you later clear the `inner` Map, you also clear the value stored in the outer Map.

If you wish the value of the outer Map to be a copy of the original inner Map, you can create a new instance :

```
outer.put(1000, new HashMap<Integer, Person>(inner));
```

Note that in this case the `Person` instances in the new inner Map would be the same instances as the original `Person` instances of the original `inner` Map, so if you mutate one of them, the instance stored in the Map would be mutated too.

Comment: replenishment for the answer: You can use something like: ``outer.put(1000, new HashMap<>(inner));``

Comment: @pL4Gu33 I just added that :)